# Elegant way of combining two LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

How can I combine these two LINQ queries in one?

```
var maxEndDate = lstDates.Select(s => s.EndDate).Max();    
var record = lstDates.Where(s => s.EndDate == maxEndDate).First();
```

Comment: I like it the way it is... readable.

Comment: Frankly, this is fine. It's very readable and it's `O(n)` (and in general you aren't going to do any better). You could look at [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) but that's arguably not really "one query" (it won't be translated into SQL if your LINQ provider is a wrap on a database).

Comment: @Jason: +1, as it's important that this is readable. If you need high performance, just do not use LINQ. LINQ is good for make things clear.

Answer (score 8):

`MaxBy` is what you are looking for: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs using it like this:

```
var record = lstDates.MaxBy(a => a.EndDate);
```

**EDIT 1:** As *Jason* pointed out this method is intended to be used only when you are working with LINQ to Objects. If you are querying against a database (and so you are using LINQ to SQL, or whatever) you should consider using a different approach.

Yours seems quite readable but, if it doesn't satisfy you, you could always call `AsEnumerable` on the `IQueryable` object and then use `MaxBy` method.

```
var record = lstDates.AsEnumerable().MaxBy(a => a.EndDate);
```

**EDIT 2:** One thing you could change in your query is the second statement. Try to shorten it as follows (in order to avoid using `Where`):

```
var record = lstDates.First(s => s.EndDate == maxEndDate);
```

Comment: Be careful, this can't be translated to SQL by any LINQ providers that I know of. It's arguable whether or not this counts as "one query."

Answer (score 2):

```
var record = lstDates.OrderByDescending(d => d.EndDate).First();
```

Comment: The OP's approach is `O(n)` whereas yours is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Performance was not a prerequisite of the question.  If the questioner wants the most performant option he can update his question.

Comment: @Jason, not necessarily; it depends on the sort algorithm used and whether it can yield the maximum element without having to do the full sort.

Comment: @Kevin Kalitowski: Sorry, but I think it's important to point out the caveats of reducing this to one query (whether it be readability, or loss of performance, or that it might not be translatable to SQL by a LINQ provider). He might not have asked for the caveats, but they are important for a complete answer.

Comment: Speaking of LINQ to SQL, this be a perfect LINQ to SQL usage since it could use an index on the EndDate column.

Answer (score 1):

Note that is actually best done *without* LINQ. Just loop through the list, keeping track of the maximum date, and the item at which that was first found:

```
DateTime maxDate = default(DateTime);
YourClass maxItem = null;

foreach (var item in lstDates)
{
    if (item.EndDate > maxDate)
    {
        maxDate = item.EndDate;
        maxItem = item;
    }
}
```

Now you only iterate once, and don't have to take the hit of sorting.

This does assume that you're using LINQ-to-Objects. If you're not, then this will retrieve the entire collection from the database (or wherever) which is undesirable. In that case, I would just use the method you already have.

Answer (score 1):

```
var record = (from r in lstDates
              orderby r.EndDate descending
              select r).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

For Link-to-Objects (Aggregate not supported in Linq-to-Sql).  Performs in N(n) (ok, actually O(n+1))

```
var record = lstDates.Aggregate(lstDates.First(), 
                                (mx, i) => i.EndDate > mx.EndDate ? i : mx));
```

For those having trouble reading that, the first parameter is the initial value for the accumulator, which would normal aggregate values in the list, but here is just holding the current highest record.  Then for each record in the list, the lambda function is called, given the current highest and the next item.  It returns the new current highest.

Comment: Aww, I was just about to post a similar solution although I agree with dlev; if you are doing Linq2Objects most devs in my experience prefer a normal for loop over .Aggregate (the opposite is true for .Where/.Select/.OrderBy in my experience).

Answer (score -1):

```
var record = lstDates.Where(s => s.EndDate == lstDates.Max(v => v.EndDate)).First();
```

Comment: This isn't an improvement, and is arguably worse as it's less readable.

Comment: While I don't disagree, the question wasn't to improve the code, the question was how to combine them.  If this had been on CodeReview, I wouldn't have given the same answer.

Comment: Actually, since the Max() would be performed each time the Where is called, we've gone from O(2n) (original), bypassed O(n ln n) (sorting), and reached O( n * n) for this one.